# Multiple reactjs applications that can share components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-6

I am creating a new rails6 application, and I need to host multiple Reactjs applications inside of this rails app.

So I will have an 'admin' section that will be React based. 
On the customer facing website it will be regular rails erb/html templates, but I have one area that needs to be react.

How can I have multiple Reactjs applications that can also share components between each other?

Comment: just like you use packages, you can create a repository that you put common helpers / elements.. then you can install via `npm`. If you dont want to host on npm itself you can always just point to the github url for your util/sdk project.

Comment: lerna helps with that - https://github.com/lerna/lerna

Answer (score 0):

> How can I have multiple Reactjs applications that can also share
>   components between each other?

You can use the package `Bit` which lets you share components between your projects.

Quote from docs:

> Bit makes it easy to share and manage components between projects and
>   apps at any scale.
>   It lets you reuse individual components across projects.

See [documentation](https://docs.bit.dev/docs/installation.html), and [GitHub repo](https://github.com/teambit/bit) for details.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways todo this, personally I use this one.

My current ongoing project also, front-end based on `erb` and admin panel using `ReactJS`.

if your app not supporting webpack, then suggesting to install it.

1) install `gem 'webpacker'`

Also update coffee-rails, for rails6. `gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 5.0.0'`

2) `bundle install`

3) `bundle exec rails webpacker:install`

4) `bundle exec rails webpacker:install:react`

> Viola: Webpacker now supports react.js

Once after installation, you will see `app/javascript/packs/application.js & hello_react.jsx`

Create routes and controllers as usually, just make sure to create and use specific layout under `app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb`

```
# sample - controllers
class AdminController < ApplicationController
    layout 'admin'
end

class SampleController < AdminController
   def index
   end
end

# create routes for this action!

# view/layouts/admin.html.erb
<head>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
</head>
```

After all, check browser console it will be logged `Hello World from Webpacker`

from `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

Everything else as default `npm` installations and etc.

### To start the rails server with webpack

`rails s & ./bin/webpack-dev-server`